# Use CArray class from MFC in C++ Builder application

Tags: c++, mfc, c++builder

There is a need to pass CArray instance to an external DLL from my application written in C++ Builder. Is there a way to utilize MFC from C++ Builder? If yes, how?

Addendum: this DLL is not mine and I cannot change it.

Comment: Also, CArray is terrible.  Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I cannot change that DLL that expects CArray instance. It's not mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ Builder doesn't support MFC because the Microsoft and Borland C++ runtimes are incompatible.

See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/compiler-dependencies.html#faq-38.9

Comment: As a consequence of this you will very likely find the external DLL will not work with C++ Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if C++ Builder has any kind of MFC support (maybe there is 3rd party open source code for that).

Since the `CArray` has few methods, one possible solution is to write a wrapper for it and expose the interface to the dll.

See for example the [adapter pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a std::vector instead.  The functionality is pretty much the same.

Comment: This DLL is not mine and I cannot change it's interface. It expects CArray and I can do nothing with it.

Answer (score 0):

CArray is very similar to a std::vector in that the data is contigous in memory.
The easiest (only safe) way is to pass a pointer to the actual data and a size parameter.
See [CArray::getData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzsdcs85(VS.80).aspx)

Your separate dll shoudln't change the size - if you need to do this use std::Vector